Clang forward slash in #include headers not reading the correct file location?
I have a header in one of my C++ projects that looks like this:
    #include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

This references a header located in Qt/6.7.2/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers. While qglobal.h exists, it is located in the .../QtCore.framework/Headers/ directory, rather than the /QtCore.framework/Headers/QtCore directory. Functionally, tree is like this:
 - QtCore
 - qglobal.h

And QtCore is a file that looks like this:
    #ifndef QT_QTCORE_MODULE_H
    #define QT_QTCORE_MODULE_H
    #include <QtCore/QtCoreDepends>
    #include "qglobal.h"
    // ...a bunch of other headers

While the above Headers directory is included in my compile_commands.json, clangd doesn't recognize the header file, and I get the following error:
'QtCore/qglobal.h' file not foundclang(pp_file_not_found)

Compiling the project with qmake works fine, but clangd just won't find the correct directory. However, when I move the header into a manually-created QtCore subdirectory, it works fine.
Is there some way to get clangd to recognize the file?

You're probably mistaken, there has to be a QtCore directory somewhre with qglobal.h in it. I bet your compile_commands.json is missing some flags. Get qmake to show the compiler commands it's running somehow, and compare them with compile_commands.json.

@HolyBlackCat Well... the only qglobal.h file on my system that I can find is in .../QtCore.framework/Versions/A/Headers/qglobal.h which is a symlink of .../QtCore.framework/Headers/. The code compiles and works fine, it's just my LSP that's causing issues.
The Makefile uses  -I../../../Qt/6.7.2/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers as the directory, which is the same ~/Qt/6.7.2/macos/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers.

Hmm. Maybe macos frameworks allow this (weird header paths) to work? Can you please show the compiler command from the build logs, and the same command in compile_commands.json?

The flag for including a framework is -framework QtCore. Don't circumvent them by including subdirectories manually.

Here are my compile commands and Makefile: https://gist.github.com/eiiot/fd504e40dee1b053c6e6b88b9aa9192a. It doesn't appear that adding -framework to the compile_commands.json makes any difference...

Try compiling with Clang directly from the terminal using the same command you have in compile_commands.json, with -fsyntax-only. (If you have multiple versions of Clang, use the one that came with Clangd.) Also can you show the compilation command that's shown when running the makefile?

Note how your Makefile correctly uses -framework flags in its LIBS variable, while your compile_commands.json does not. Were both of these generated from the same QMake file?

I was able to fix it using a different compile_commands.json generated directly by qmake via QT Creator: https://gist.github.com/eiiot/0f0446f4f105369f52aeb705cb8cce15. This doesn't use the -framework flag, but still works fine?
